# Have a button that changes what is in the table (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

(Very beginner user btw. I tried my best to explain)

I've got a text box, a button, and a table. In the app, you put a number in the box, then press the button and the table should populate for, 10 rows, that number input multiplied by the row number.

This is the code I've got so far.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var inputText: UITextField!
    
    @IBAction func goButton(_ sender: Any) {

        let input: Int? = Int(inputText.text!)

        // should the multiplication happen here or in the tableView func??
        // let result: Int? = INDEX OF ROW * input!

        //table values should change when button is pressed
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  
        let aCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "aCell", for: indexPath)
        var content = UIListContentConfiguration.cell()

        // content = result

        aCell.contentConfiguration = content
        return aCell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

How do I link the button to the table so that the values in the table will change when a user puts a number into the box and then pressed the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you actually have a `UITableView` setup as an outlet in this view controller, all you need to do is call `tableView.reloadData()` in the `goButton` function.

Then in `cellForRowAt` you get the row number as `indexPath.row`. Multiply that by the entered number and supply the number to the cell configuration.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var inputText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weka var tableView: UITableView! // This needs to be added and setup if you don't actually have it
    
    @IBAction func goButton(_ sender: Any) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let aCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "aCell", for: indexPath)

        var content = UIListContentConfiguration.cell()
        let result = indexPath.row * (Int(inputText.text!) ?? 0)
        content.text = "\(result)"

        aCell.contentConfiguration = content
        return aCell
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code you need to ensure you actually have a table view setup.

The `goButton` method simply reloads the table view.

The `cellForRowAt` calculates the result for the row and passes it to the cell configuration.

Comment: Thank you . Quick question: If I wanted to hide the table on start-up, then show it when the user enters a value. How would I do that?

Comment: That's a whole new question. I suggest giving it a try and then posting a new question specific to any issues you have trying to make that work. But as a hint - look at the `isHidden` property from UIView (which UITableView inherits from).

Comment: Appreciate it! Got it working.